# ¿Cómo itero sobre un objeto en React Native?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, react-native, diccionarios

Estoy trabajando en React Native en algo parecido a esto:

```
render() {
    let fuentes = ["fuente1", "fuente2"];
    const renderEsto = fuentes.map((f) => {
        return (
                <Text>{ f }</Text>
        );
    });

    return (
        { renderEsto }    
    )
}
```

Es decir, tengo una lista `fuentes` e itero sobre ella con [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objectes_globals/Array/map) para mostrar los datos.

Ahora bien, resulta que por circunstancias debo cambiar la lista y tratar con un objeto del tipo:

```
let fuentes = {
   "fuente1": "cierta info",
   "fuente2": "algo más"
 };
```

Y querría utilizar algo parecido al `map()` para iterar sobre índice y valor, para tener acceso tanto a `fuente1` como a `cierta info` en la primera iteración, `fuente2` en la 2.ª, etc.

He probado con

```
const renderEsto = fuentes.forEach((f, texto) => {
    ...
}
```

Pero me dice que:

> TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...fuentes.forEach...')

¿Cómo itero sobre un array en React Native?

Comment: No existe un método propio de React para iterar objetos, puedes revisar la misma pregunta en el sitio en ingles [How to loop an object in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965579/how-to-loop-an-object-in-react), aunque las respuestas son semejantes a las que te respondieron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que tienes no es un array, sino un objeto, lo puedes recorrer con un `for` por ejemplo:

```js
let fuentes = {
   "fuente1": "cierta info",
   "fuente2": "algo más"
 };
 
 for(i in fuentes){
  console.log(i,':', fuentes[i]);
 }
```

otra forma puede ser con un `keys` y `forEach` así:

```js
let fuentes = {
   "fuente1": "cierta info",
   "fuente2": "algo más"
 };
 
 Object.keys(fuentes).forEach((e) => { 
  console.log(e,':', fuentes[e]);
 });
```

para poder iterarlo con `map` se puede usar `values` para tener solo los valores:

```js
let fuentes = {
   "fuente1": "cierta info",
   "fuente2": "algo más"
 };
 
 Object.values(fuentes).map(e => 
  console.log(e)
 );
```

Comment: Mmmm ¿pero no hay ninguna función de ECMA del tipo `fuentes.map()` para hacer lo mismo? Me resulta muy útil poder hacerlo así para construir bloques con React Native.

Comment: @fedorqui prueba la segunda con `keys` y `foreach`

Comment: @fedorqui si quieres iterarlo con `map` puedes usar `Object.values`